# Countexample for Fubini-Tonelli

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a function $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ I want to show that the Integrals $\int_{\Bbb R}(\int_{\Bbb R}f(x,y)\,dv(x))dv(y)$ and $\int_{\Bbb R}(\int_{\Bbb R}f(x,y)\,dv(y))dv(x)$ both exist and are equal, but $\int_{\Bbb R^2}f(x,y)\,d(v\otimes v)(x,y)$ doesn't exist.

Where $v$ denotes the density function of the Normal/Gaussian distribution, with mean $0$ and variance $1$

So far I was only able to  show that the inner part of one of the integrals exists as it is positive, but I have absolutely no idea how i would continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y) dv(x) = 0$ by symmetry.

In polar coordinates, $f(x,y) = r^{-2} \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$.  The
factor $r^{-2}$ ensures that $f$ is not integrable with respect to Lebesgue measure in a neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have seen that symmetry...
I just don't understand, how $r^{-2}$ makes $f$ not Lebesgue integrable

Comment: In polar coordinates, two-dimensional Lebesgue measure is $r \; dr \; d\theta$, and $\int_0^1 r^{-1}\; dr = \infty$.

Comment: Okay I think I got. Just for verification, the fact that $v$ is the normal distribution doesn't matter when showing the nonexistence of the integral? So is it enough to show it doesn't exists with respect to Lebesgue measure and thus it doesn't exist for any other measure aswell?

Comment: It doesn't exist for any other measure  that is greater than a positive constant multiple of Lebesgue measure in a neighbourhood of the origin.